# JSF 2 messages in Validator

Tags: java, jsf

I had a doubt regarding Messages being set in the custom validator in JSF 2.0.
here is the code

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
    if(!matcher.matches()){

        FacesMessage msg = 
            new FacesMessage("E-mail validation failed.", 
                    "Invalid E-mail format.");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);

    }

}
```

Now here I am curious about how is it actually working, since we **haven't** written the part of the code
        **context.add(msg)**

SO without adding these messages in the FacesContext how does it manage to retrieve it on the UI???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF does that in [the `UIInput#validateValue()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#validateValue%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Object%29). It just calls your validator inside a `try-catch` block, catches the `ValidatorException`, extracts the `FacesMessage` from it and finally adds it to the `FacesContext` on component's client ID.

JSF implementations are open source. In [Mojarra 2.1.3](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) source code you can find the following starting at line 1143 of the `UIInput` class:

```
// If our value is valid and not empty or empty w/ validate empty fields enabled, call all validators
if (isValid() && (!isEmpty(newValue) || validateEmptyFields(context))) {
    if (validators != null) {
        Validator[] validators = this.validators.asArray(Validator.class);
        for (Validator validator : validators) {
            try {
                validator.validate(context, this, newValue);
            }
            catch (ValidatorException ve) {
                // If the validator throws an exception, we're
                // invalid, and we need to add a message
                setValid(false);
                FacesMessage message;
                String validatorMessageString = getValidatorMessage();

                if (null != validatorMessageString) {
                    message =
                          new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                           validatorMessageString,
                                           validatorMessageString);
                    message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                } else {
                    Collection<FacesMessage> messages = ve.getFacesMessages();
                    if (null != messages) {
                        message = null;
                        String cid = getClientId(context);
                        for (FacesMessage m : messages) {
/* Here --> */              context.addMessage(cid, m);
                        }
                    } else {
                        message = ve.getFacesMessage();
                    }
                }
                if (message != null) {
/* And here --> */  context.addMessage(getClientId(context), message); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsf has a catch exception in back and he is retrieving your message..

If this doesn't answer your question I don't understand your question...

maybe this link will help you:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-validation-tutorial-error

You have to set a place for errors in jsf as well..

Comment: in the link provided by you, it has the snippet -"context.addMessage("userForm:Email", message);" , that what I am  askin' without context.add() how is the message reaching the UI?